# scanf() but arbitrary order of data type

Tags: c, stack

I'm creating a program that evaluates postfix expression, e.g. `12 2 + 3 *` means `(12+2)*3 = 42`. I want to `push` the numbers in a stack and `pop` out two numbers if the input is not a number. But I can't seem to figure out how to check if the input is an integer or a character. I've tried

```
char x;
scanf("%c", &x);
```

and use `isdigit()` to check if it's a digit but the problem is when the number has more than one digit. How can I solve this?

Comment: If it's a digit then you can keep reading in digits until you find a character that's not a digit.

Comment: If a digit then you multiply your accumulator x 10 and add the current digit.

Comment: I would read in a whole line and parse it myself. Inspecting each char in turn. Not an answer to your digit question but just general point

Comment: How do I combine the digits as a whole number? Do I need to create an int array to store the digits of the number?

Comment: You multiply an accumulator by 10 and add the digit. If it is not a digit you push the accumulator and zero it for next time.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you and thank you all. I know now.